# Matrix Invertibility: $AB$ invertible implies $A,B$ invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

$AB$ invertible

$\implies$ $AB$ is the product of elementary matrices.

$\implies$ $A, B$ are the product of elementary matrices.

$\implies$ $A, B$ are invertible since the products of elementary matrices are always invertible.

Comment: It's not clear how you get from "AB is the product of elementary matrices" to "A, B are the product of elementary matrices".  In fact, this seems like a rather subtle statement about elementary matrices.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom did a great job of pointing out a weakness in your proof. There is an easier proof if you can use the theorem that an $n\times n$ matrix is invertible if and only if its rank is $n$.

Comment: For students reading this, an assumption has been omitted from the antecedents: A and B must be square matrices in order for this theorem to be true as stated. If A and B are arbitrary matrices, the theorem is false. As an example, consider $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Then $AA^T$ is invertible, but neither A nor $A^T$ are invertible (only left or right-invertible).

Answer (score 2):

Easier method: note that $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$.

Comment: I'm trying not to use determinants- how does this work: AB invertible $\implies$ $ \exists$ some matrix Z s.t. Z(AB) = I ; (AB)Z= I $\implies$ (ZA)B=I $\implies$ ZA=$B^{-1}$ and then do something similar to show A inverse exists?

Comment: That works. Also note $BZ=A^{-1}$. You are implicitly making some assumptions about inverses, but those assumptions are probably fine.

Comment: I did- Thanks for your input. I appreciate it